# VB.NET and OOP - Shared Methods and Base Properties

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

If you can't use `Me.` in a non-instance method, how would you use properties/functions from a base class in a `Shared` method?

For example, `ClassB` inherits from `ClassA`
`ClassB` has a `Shared Method DoWork()`;
`ClassA` has a `ReadOnly Property SecurityKey`

How do I …

```
Public Sub DoWork()
  Dim test as String = Me.SecurityKey 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you can't use "Me." in a non-instance method, how would you use properties/functions from a base class in a Shared method?

You can't. Shared methods (and `static` in C#) don't work well together with OOP. This (i.e. the fact that static/shared methods cannot be virtual/overridable) is [arguably](http://www.jwz.org/doc/java.html) a design flaw in the .NET system that was “inherited” from Java. Shared methods aren't actually object methods, rather they are global methods with a name scope.

Additionally, and perhaps even more related to your problem, you always need an instance to access a non-shared method (which, being shared, does not belong to any particular instance).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm trying to help some fix a VB.NET mess written by a completely non-OOP guy. And I'm trying to bolt in some OOP to clean up the mess. I think the person was using Shared methods from his "Class B"s to work with Object DataSources in ASP.NET... which I wouldn't have used those either

Comment: but hey.... I'm trying to clean up someone else's problem without rewriting the whole thing. The person thought they were writing business objects and they are more like "table gateway" classes.

Answer (score 2):

You access shared members by the classname and not an instance identifier.. IE: `ClassA.DoWork()`  You cannot access instance members from shared methods/members because they are different scope.  However you can access shared members from instance scope without using the instance identifier.

Try passing an instance of the class to your method or instantiating the class in the shared method.

```
Public Shared Sub DoWork(instance As ClassB)
    Dim test As String = instance.WhateverProperty;
End Sub
```

Comment: I noticed if I mark my property shared in ClassA I can use it... but still can't use the prefix "Me." Is there a prefix/keyword to use? Some visual cue/hint that this available because of a class I inherited from?

Comment: No, you can use the class explorer to help you see the modifiers different members of your class have, but you will not be able to access Shared/static members of an object with an instance identifier like Me/this.  The best way to remember is if it is marked Shared then it is always ClassName.XXX

Answer (score 1):

Using your examples:

Which `ClassA` instance should the shared `ClassB.DoWork()` get when it tries to reference the `Me.SecurityKey` property?

If you make the `ClassA.SecurityKey` property also shared that would make a little more sense, but then the inheritance relationship is no longer important.  You might just as well say `ClassA.SecurityKey` inside that method, because you would have to already know about ClassA to know about it's inherited property anyway.

If you make `ClassB.DoWork()` as an instance method rather than a shared method, you can use the `MyBase` keyword in VB.Net to reference the inherited ClassA property, even if ClassB overloads or shadows it.

Comment: +1. Good points. And I think it was MyBase keyword I was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a static context, you would need to instantiate this class to access its instance members.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim s as SecKey = ClassA.SecurityKey
```

This pulls from a shared method. Remember that shared methods are shared by all instances of a class, so you use the class name to pull them.